# How to add the uri and database in readConfig for mongo db in Spark?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

In the below code i tried to pass the mongo uri and database in readConfig using options map. But its giving error that uri or database are not found.

`

```
public JavaMongoRDD<Document> getRDDFromDS(DataSourceInfo ds, String collectionName){
        String mongoDBURI = "mongodb://"
                + PropertiesFileEncryptorUtil.decryptData(ds.getDbUsername()) + ":"
                + PropertiesFileEncryptorUtil.decryptData(ds.getDbPassword()) + "@"
                + ds.getHostName() + ":" + ds.getPort();
        Map<String, String> readOverrides = new HashMap<String, String>();
        readOverrides.put("uri", mongoDBURI);
        readOverrides.put("database", ds.getDbName());
        readOverrides.put("collection", collectionName);
        readOverrides.put("partitioner", mongoDBInputPartitioner);
        readOverrides.put("partitionKey", mongoDBPartitionKey);
        readOverrides.put("partitionSizeMB", mongoDBInputPartitionSize);

        ReadConfig readConf = ReadConfig.create(jsc).withOptions(readOverrides);
        JavaMongoRDD<Document> readRdd = MongoSpark.load(jsc, readConf);
        return readRdd;
    }`
```

What is the right way to pass the uri and database .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of the spark connector are you using?  I think that bug has already been fixed. Also you can create the readConf with the options directly.

Comment: I am using the 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.0.0-rc1' , will i need to change this as i am using the gradle and found the above as the latest one on maven in which issue for 100 mb size sort was fixed last time. Now i checked and found 2.0.0 is the latest one , i am trying with 2.0.0 and let you know.

Comment: @Ross ,thanks for your quick response i am testing with 2.0.0 version, can you please help me how to pass the use ssl flag for mongo client while passing read config.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass configuration parameter to spark through the configuration variable:

```
 val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("YourAppName").setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","1g")
      .set("spark.app.id","YourSparkId")
      .set("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/yourdatabase.yourInputcollection?readPreference=primaryPreferred")
      .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri","mongodb://127.0.0.1/yourdatabase.yourOutputcollection")
```

After that you need to give the configuration variable to the spark context:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val readConf = ReadConfig( sc )
```

Then you can read values from mongo like this:

```
 val rdd = sc.loadFromMongoDB( readConfig = readConfig )
```

And save like this:

```
rdd.map( someMapFunction ).saveToMongoDB()
```

I hope my answer was helpful

Comment: thanks for your response . I did the same that you suggest in my last code . But now we need to select different data source dynamically which are hosted on different host machines so i need to pass the uri and database as read config not with SparkConf while creating sparkcontext. As only single sparkcontext is recommanded in one application setting uri in sparkcontext initialization is not seems suitable for this use case.

Comment: Is this possible to provide uri and database in sparkcontext initialization and then override uri and database via readconfig.

Comment: I don't know your second question, but If my first answer meets your question, please accept/upvote it.